# Up-vote on bounty offered question doesn't add points?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

I received an upvote on this question [Static-analysis with custom rules for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816713/static-analysis-with-custom-rules-for-javascript) but it didn't add any points, 5 reputation points is not a loss .

But do bounty offered question are blocked from receiving reputation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has become [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) because it has been edited too many times. You don't earn reputation from posts that have converted to community wiki status.

Comment: That explains everything :)